# .htaccess remove question mark from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website that has an query string in the url that I want to rewrite. The url is `domain.com/profile.php?user=sven` and I want it to redirect to `domain.com/profile/user/sven`.

I have created a htaccess file that has the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?user/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)$
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ domain.com/user/%1?/  [L,R=301]
```

This works but the url it redirects to is: `domain.com/user/sven?/`

My question is, can I remove the `?` in the url?

Comment: You've written the ? in the redirect yourself: `domain.com/user/%1?/`. Just remove it.

Comment: Hi Gerald Schneider, when I removed the ? after %1, the query string gets appended to the url after the rewrite. Now it looks like this :user/sven/?user=sven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your htaccess to following,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*?)/?$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profile\.php\?user=([^]+)
RewriteRule ^/?profile\.php$ /users/%1? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick reply. I have tried your code and it works partially, the url gets rewritten and redirected but now I get a redirection loop. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I've removed the unwanted rule, try now.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the edit. Now the page gets redirected correct with no query string behind it. Only problem now is that the page is not found. Any idea on what causes this?

Comment: Let me check the issue.

Comment: Updated answer try now and see if the issue is still there. I hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have tried this answer and I still get the page is not found..

Comment: Your answer is valid **+1** , but there is no need to eacape & and \ space inside char class in the cond.

Answer (score 1):

Probaly all the problem here:

```
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ domain.com/user/%1?/ [L,R=301]
```

This may fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply! Sadly the problem still exists.